# 2560 x 1440 Resolution: is Mini DisplayPort or HDMI better?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, displayport, high-definition, mini-displayport

My first foray *beyond* 1080p begins today.

Should I use HDMI or DisplayPort to connect my new laptop to my monitor?

If I have both cables, which will allow me to maximize my graphics experience?

Hardware:

- 27" Monitor resolution is **2560 x 1440** (ASUS PB278Q)
- Alienware laptop, video card supports up to 3840 x 2160.  (Dual GeForce GTX 880M graphics card, 2x8GB GDDR5 NVIDIA SLI)

Both have both ports.

If DisplayPort is better, then in what aspects is it superior?

If HDMI is better, then how can I know what HDMI version my cable is? I have the Rocketfish RF-G1167. It only says "High Speed HDMI Cable with Ethernet CL2 UL" but no version # anywhere, nor can I find it online.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You gain nothing since your monitor doesn't support very high resolution ( its good but your laptop supports much better resolution )

Comment: Edited to clarify.  Basically I want the best graphics experience I can get with my hardware.  To do this, I want to know which cable to use, if there is any difference.  If DisplayPort is better, I'd like to know in what ways it is superior.  If HDMI is better, I'd like to know how to find out what HDMI version my cable is.

Comment: Based on your monitor both cables would provide you **exactly** the same refresh rate and resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with the DisplayPort. Although the high speed HDMI cable offers true 4k (4096 x 2160) and the DisplayPort only offers 4k formatted for 16:9 i believe (3840 x 2160), the DisplayPort offers a refresh rate of up to 60hz, while the HDMI is limited to 24hz, and both surpass your resolution needs.

You can find more info here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2030669/hdmi-vs-displayport-which-display-interface-reigns-supreme-.html

Comment: The refresh rate would be limited by the monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound The refresh rate is limited by the lowest value. If you have a 120hz monitor, but your cable caps at 24hz, then the output is going to be 24hz.

Comment: I looked up the monitor if your wondering.  Its not a 4k monitor.  His monitor only supports 75 refresh rate.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  I realize this is a personal opinion, but: Is C2G as good of a brand as Accell?  What about StarTech?  Never heard of any of them.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never heard of any of those either, nor do I know any displayport cable brands. Although I remember reading somewhere that because of the way they work, you won't really get a slightly better experience by buying a more expensive cable. All you should look for is a reliable one. If you like I can look for the article.

Comment: That would be wonderful if you could find it!!

Comment: Alright, I believe this is the one. And good luck on your endeavor. http://www.displayport.org/cables/how-to-choose-a-displayport-cable-and-not-get-a-bad-one/

Comment: Thank you!!  I ran into that one as well, and it really helped clarify things.

Comment: HDMI 2 also supports higher resolutions @60hz now.

Comment: Also see the updated table: http://www.planar.com/blog/2014/12/15/displayport-13-vs-hdmi-20/

Answer (score 3):

Since your display supports HDMI 1.4 and, according to Wikipedia, 2560×1600p75 is supported since HDMI 1.3, you’ll face no problems when using HDMI. For your intent, it is absolutely equal to DisplayPort.

HDMI cables are no longer “versioned”. Instead, they are separated into “Standard” and “High Speed”, with the latter being capable of 4K etc. So your cable is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that people seem to be missing here is that display port and HDMI port on a laptop are limited to their output setting from the video card. All laptops that I know of will only output 108o out of the HDMI port. Higher resolutions would come from the display port or DVI. HDMI is mainly used for HOME video and sound products and the standard has been 1080 over HDMI. Computers have used HDMI and display port but use the higher resolution over display port and DVI. Even though u may have a HDMI cable that can support 4K res, Your video card doesn't ouput that high res out HDMI port. All high res monitors that I have seen only accept display port and DVI for resolutions higher than 1080

Answer (score 1):

In your case, DisplayPort is probably going to be the better option. The newest DisplayPort standard (1.2) supports 21.6 Gbit/s bandwidth, while the newest HDMI (2.0) standard only supports a bandwidth of 18 Gbits/s.

Your RF-G1167 can't be any higher than 1.2, and, as such, won't support Ultra-HD resolutions (according to the page on the BestBuy website). I can only guess that they don't want to tell you what version it is since it's probably pretty old. (I haven't had the best experience with Rocketfish. I don't recommend buying that brand unless you absolutely have to.)

If you're going to spend money on a new cable, buying a new DisplayPort won't be much more expensive than buying a new HDMI cable, especially if you buy online (i.e from Amazon).

Comment: Most sources that I have read (including Wikipedia) suggest that there are various HDMI standards supporting different resolutions. According to Wikipedia's [Version Comparison] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison), versions 1.2 and below will not support the resolution he desires. The page on BestBuy's website claims that the cable doesn't support more than 1080p. Admittedly, the information could be inaccurate, but without the product to test I cannot be sure.

Comment: Thank you!  Extremely helpful. (Very hard to select a best answer, but the refresh rate pushed his up.) I'm trying to figure out which brand, any suggestions?

Comment: Any brand should be good, so long as it meets the correct specifications. Just looking briefly at Amazon, [this one](http://amzn.to/1qVI3i3) looks nice. It's not the newest DisplayPort version as far as I can tell, but it should support the resolution you need. If you're looking for the newest version (i.e., you want something you can use in the future for higher resolution displays), you could go with [Accell](http://amzn.to/UjTs0r). However, you could also just wait for the new 1.3 standard to come out later this year.

Answer (score -1):

Displayport is the way to go, because it was meant exactly for this. HDMI has a lower bandwidth and some videocards will natively have DisplayPort as extra channel, but limit the use of HDMI+DVI.

For example, if you have an ATI card, you can have 2 DVI ports, or a DVI and HDMI port, but not 2 DVI and HDMI port. However, next to 2 of these, you can have a display port as third option, and this is crucial if you want to go for a 3 monitor setup now or in the future.

For your information, my 3rd monitor is my TV connected through HDMI. Main display, 27" @2560x1440 over display port, and second display is a 24" 1200x1920 (in portrait mode)